# between (range) in mongodb query does not work

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a db doc as follow:

[image]

Now I am trying to group by all info by time  between for 2 specific time and return the sum of count

for that I wrote my code as follow:

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("test");
    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$time");
    groupFields.put("sum", new BasicDBObject("$sum", "$count"));
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
    // filter where clause
    BasicDBObject simpleQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    simpleQuery.put("time", new BasicDBObject("$gt", "20140005150011"));
    simpleQuery.put("time", new BasicDBObject("$lt", "20151105150011"));
    DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", simpleQuery);
    List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, group);
    AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(pipeline);
    for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
        System.out.println(result);
```

when I run this code it group by all elements even those time that starts with 2013...but in simpleQuery I defined a range which apparently does not work . However as soon as I remove
simpleQuery.put("time", new BasicDBObject("$lt", "20151105150011")); the code starts working. Why does it happen ? Can anyone help?

Update1 :

it seems that in the following query the second one overwrite the first one:

```
     simpleQuery.put("time", new BasicDBObject("$gt", "20140005150011"));
     simpleQuery.put("time", new BasicDBObject("$lt", "20151105150011"));
```

because when I change the query it starts working

Update 2 :

when I change the code to the following it completely work:

```
BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    simpleQuerytest.put("time", new BasicDBObject("$gt", "20130005150011"));
    simpleQuery.put("time", new BasicDBObject("$lt", "20151105150011"));

      List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
      obj.add(simpleQuerytest);
      obj.add(simpleQuery);
      andQuery.put("$and", obj);
```

Now my question is what is the difference between and query and just using put ? I always thought that they are the same !!! can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference variable `simpleQuery` points to an instance of `BasicDBObject`, which is an implementation of a `Map`. From the java docs, when you put a key value pair into the map, it,

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map
>   (optional operation). **If the map previously contained a mapping for
>   the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.** (A map m is
>   said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k)
>   would return true.)

The first operation:

```
simpleQuery.put("time", new BasicDBObject("$gt", "20140005150011"));
```

associates the key `time` to a value.

The second operation,

```
simpleQuery.put("time", new BasicDBObject("$lt", "20151105150011"));
```

**replaces** the previous value of the key `time`. Hence only the last inserted value of `time` gets associated to it.

The below operation works as intended because, `simpleQuerytest` and `simpleQuery` are two different Maps, which form the input to the `map` containing the `and` operation.

```
BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();
simpleQuerytest.put("time", new BasicDBObject("$gt", "20130005150011"));
simpleQuery.put("time", new BasicDBObject("$lt", "20151105150011"));
...
andQuery.put("$and", obj);
```

Comment: Thanks a lo Can you please take a look at this question as well?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079466/how-to-update-just-one-element-of-array-when-updating