# how to update just one element of array when updating

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a doc like the following:
[image]

as you can see I have an array entity: {1,3,4}

Now I want to just change 4 to 10 in that array and update it for that I have the following code:

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("test");
    BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject().append("time", "20141105230000");

    coll.update(searchQuery, newDocument);
    String[] str = { "1", "3", "10" };
    DBObject updateMatchingElem = new BasicDBObject("$set",
            new BasicDBObject().append("entity", str));
    coll.update(searchQuery, updateMatchingElem);
```

But this way is not a good way because I kind of remove entity and then insert the whole array again. Is there anyway that I can just change the one element like 4 to 10?

Comment: I'll give you a hint in mongo native driver: `db.collection.update({"entity":4},{$set:{"entity.$":10}})`. You can try to implement it in Java. In mongodb you can at most update only one single matching array element in a single query, even if there are other matching elements in the array. For instance, if there are two 4s in the array, only the first occurance of 4 will get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Now I want to just change 4 to 10 in that array and update it*

You can do it in the following way, using the [$](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) positional operator.

```
 //db.collection.update({"entity":4},{$set:{"entity.$":10}})
  DBObject find = new BasicDBObject( "entity", 4);
  DBObject set = new BasicDBObject( "entity.$", 10);
  DBObject update = new BasicDBObject().append("$set", set);
  coll.update(find, update);
```

Note that you can at most update only one single matching array element, even if there are other matching elements in the array. For instance, if there are two `4s` in the array, only the **first** occurrence of 4 will get updated. This is how the positional operator works.

Whenever you use the positional operator in the update query, the find query **must** contain the field in the `find` part of the query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this code works well but when I try to for example just update the entity in the instance that the name is for example john it does not work I use the following code:BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject().append("name", "john");
 BasicDBObject find = new BasicDBObject( "entity", 1000);  BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();
   List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
   obj.add(searchQuery);
   obj.add(find);
   andQuery.put("$and", obj);  and then I feed and query to update command but nothing happens is it possible to do that ?

Comment: change it to: `DBObject find = new BasicDBObject( "entity", 1000).append("name","john")`

Comment: So just a quick question :does  entity.$ means replacing element array?

Comment: No. it is accessing the first element in the entity array, which has matched the criteria in the find clause. For clarity you can go through the link in that i have provided on the `$` symbol.